# how can I simulate EXC_RESOURCE exception on iOS Device

Tags: ios, exception, crash, mach

I would like to simulate **Resource Limit [EXC_RESOURCE]** Mach Exception on iOS.

Exception Type:  **EXC_RESOURCE**
Exception Subtype: **CPU_FATAL / WAKEUPS / MEMORY**

Can someone help me write some bad code for testing that can help simulate some of these exceptions for my app on an iOS Device.

More details about this [exception](http://www.5neo.be/understanding-ios-exception-types/)